# Get random block

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I have blocks with ID's from `block1` to `block10`.

Like this:

```
<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2"></div>
<div id="block3"></div>
<div id="block4"></div>
<div id="block5"></div>
<div id="block6"></div>
<div id="block7"></div>
<div id="block8"></div>
<div id="block9"></div>
<div id="block10"></div>
```

**How do I get random block, with id range from 1 to 10?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
var obj = document.getElementById('block' + randomnumber);
```

jQuery:

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;
var obj = $('#block' + randomnumber);
```

Comment: +1. The only change I'd make is using jQuery, since he tagged it jQuery I imagine he's using it: `$('#block' + randomnumber);`

Comment: You could also make the answer a little more thorough by explaining how the random number selection works (or at least linking to something that explains it)

Comment: @Happy: The +1 was in reference to my voting for his answer, and had nothing to do with the actual content of the answer.

Comment: @jball this line "Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1;"

Comment: +1 for the random number to be min 1. Math.floor(Math.random()*10) returns 0-9 while Math.floor(Math.random()*10) + 1 returns 1-10

Comment: The 11 dictates that the random number will fall between 0-10. To increase the range to, say, 100, simply change 11 to 101 instead. I just posted an answer with the full code

Answer (score 2):

First get a random number between 1 and 10

var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

Then get the element with the id + num.

var element = document.getElementById('block'+num);

Comment: `var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);` returns a number between 0 and 11 inclusive. `var element = document.getElementById('block'+0);` will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate a random number using javascript and then just use a jQuery selector like

```
var randomNumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
var chosenBlock = $('#block'+randomNumber);
```

Where 11 dictates that the random number will fall between 0-10. To increase the range to, say, 100, simply change 11 to 101 instead.

**EDIT:**
Remember to number your blocks starting in 0.

Comment: Copying/pasting my comment from Jonathon's answer, you've made the same inclusive 0 range mistake: `var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);` returns a number between 0 and 11 inclusive. `var chosenBlock = $('#block'+0);` will fail.

Comment: Partly copied from http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/randomnum.shtml please always add attribution.

Answer (score 2):

The first two answers posted are not quite right. They will retrieve numbers from 0 to 10 since they use floor, not 1 to 10.

Random number calculation works like this:

1. Math.random returns a decimal value ranging from 0 to 1, BUT NEITHER 0 NOR 1.
2. Multiplying that decimal value by 10 makes it range from about 0.000001 to 9.99999.
3. Using the Math.floor on the result will remove the decimal so the answer is now between 0 and 9.
4. Add 1 to the number to offset its range to 1 to 10.

The full code is this:

```
var randNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
var randId = 'block' + randNumber;

var obj = document.GetElementById(randId);
```

Now obj holds the div object, and randId is the id of the random div. Or you could have used jQuery on the last line instead:

```
var obj = $('#' + randId);
```